# Intersection of Discriminated Union Types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an intersection of discriminated union types. After trying it many different ways, I've discovered the `keyof` operator, which appears to have worked. However, when I generalize the operator into a partial function, it does not work.

```
class Account { ... }
type ILoggedIn =
  | { isLoggedIn: boolean; loggedInUser?: any }
  | { isLoggedIn: false; loggedInUser?: undefined }
  | { isLoggedIn: true; loggedInUser?: any }

type IInitialized =
  | { initialized: boolean; account?: undefined }
  | { initialized: false; account?: undefined }
  | { initialized: true; account?: Account }

type IContextWorks = { [K in keyof ILoggedIn]?: ILoggedIn[K] } &
  { [K in keyof IInitialized]?: IInitialized[K] }

type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] }
type IContextNotWork = Partial<ILoggedIn> & Partial<IInitialized>

const valueWorks: IContextWorks = {
  account: new Account(),
  initialized: true,
  isLoggedIn: true,
  loggedInUser: {},
}
const valueNotWork: IContextNotWork = {
  account: new Account(),
  initialized: true,
  isLoggedIn: true,
  loggedInUser: {},
}
```

The error I get when I use the `NotWork` version is:

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true | undefined'.
```

I would assume that either both would work or both would not work, but in this case only one works.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is `IXyaInitialized`?  And I [can't reproduce](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCzAPYFcB2AXaBvAvgKD3QE8AHAU2gEkAZRAczrIBNLVoBePaaAH22gCWEWg2asAXNABGiRCDJhUAbmgh6jFqgCqEMgCcA-JMVFo+bnyyDh6sakkAzMCF0q1ozTv1HoaJmQcBVGYzLl5+IRENCWh0PWQyN1tPXUNjVFMcJQJicipWAXQBZwEALxDOCwjUQuKQMuZJGTkFZWgwBBQMHz8AoJDzcKsg2pLypkdnV3bOtHQe1H9A4KZQquGaorHG2PjEmaQ5n3hDjDNswlIKSgBhRAwyAA90ADlEdAB1RD0Aaw5oAAKYD0WxAAB4aMlWAA+aAAMkBwNBEIKoIaTGhFyQqAgmAAbs4Em9Pt8fpJbvd0E9Xu8vr9-lgwh1TuhJMEAO5wWYYAAUAEoADRhEZo8aSOIJIXcSJQ+y7SVhdzRbSpSS4PBZPBAA) your error.

Comment: Also, `IContextWorks` is no longer a discriminated union.  Discriminated union: `{kind: "s", value:  string} | {kind: "n", value: number}`.  Not: `{kind: "s" | "n", value: string | number}`.  Specifically a value like `{kind: "s", value: 7}` matches the latter type but not the former type.

Comment: Interesting, can't reproduce in the playground either. Sorry, I fixed the `IXyaInitialized`, I was just renaming some variables to be more clear. I'm trying to set a boolean based on the existence of a certain property. I'm not sure if this is the purpose of a discriminated union, in which case, what pattern would help me accomplish this? I have async functions that update the `account` and `loggedInUser` properties so it's important that the consumer has these booleans for guarding.

Comment: My understanding is you're trying to create a union of 9 intersection types, is that right?

Comment: You could use discriminated unions for this, but really if you are only looking for the existence of a property you don't need to store a separate boolean for it, you can just calculate that boolean when you need it... (e.g., `typeof value.account !== 'undefined'`)

Comment: If you can't reproduce the issue in a standalone environment then I guess your next step is to analyze the environment in which you see the error and try to figure out what's different.  If the error only occurs in a certain version of TypeScript or with a certain set of compiler options, then that's relevant to the question and should be edited in.  Good luck!

Comment: @hackape I think it's the other way around -- an intersection of 6 union types. @jcalz that makes sense but this was a simplistic example. I'm trying to make a single boolean that tells the app if all the async stuff is done loading, so there would be multiple properties, and would need to be used in multiple places. I could just do `typeof value.account !== 'undefined' && typeof value.foo !== 'undefined'` etc etc but it could get a bit unwieldy when it grows. I follow that pattern when not using TS but is it possible to inform that using TS? Thanks!

Comment: @abustamam I'm a bit confused. Be it tedious, can you manually type out the expected result to help clarify what you want?

Comment: @hackape something like this worked for me, but I'm not even sure if it's the right way to express what I want. https://gist.github.com/abustamam/b18c753e741e0b579a9cc57c39b32198

Answer (score 0):

I think the only sensible result that's deducible looks like below.

```js
type UnionOfIntersections =
    | { isLoggedIn: boolean; loggedInUser?: any } & { initialized: boolean; account?: undefined }
    | { isLoggedIn: boolean; loggedInUser?: any } & { initialized: false; account?: undefined }
    | { isLoggedIn: boolean; loggedInUser?: any } & { initialized: true; account?: Account }
    | { isLoggedIn: false; loggedInUser?: undefined } & { initialized: boolean; account?: undefined }
    | { isLoggedIn: false; loggedInUser?: undefined } & { initialized: false; account?: undefined }
    | { isLoggedIn: false; loggedInUser?: undefined } & { initialized: true; account?: Account }
    | { isLoggedIn: true; loggedInUser?: any } & { initialized: boolean; account?: undefined }
    | { isLoggedIn: true; loggedInUser?: any } & { initialized: false; account?: undefined }
    | { isLoggedIn: true; loggedInUser?: any } & { initialized: true; account?: Account }
```

And I think what you mark as "not work" actually produces above result correctly.

```
type IContextNotWork = Partial<ILoggedIn> & Partial<IInitialized>
```

Comment: Is there a way to see what the end result type of a union/intersection looks like, or is the only way to do that to do some unit testing?

Comment: [ts-playground](https://typescriptlang.org/play/). I always try things out there first. mouse hover can tell alot useful information